# Select options to populate database with both name and value in Rails 2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In the following example, How can I save both name and id in the database? id would be saved if I use the following code but what if I have to save p.name also?? any ideas???

```
<%= f.label :person_id, "Person ID" %><br />
<%=select :post, :person_id, Person.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to the index method in the posts  controller and try adding the following line:

```
@posts.person_name = (Person.find(:first, :conditions => ['id=?', "%#{params[:person_id]}%"])).name
```

Comment: Well I added a method in my Post model saying 
return Person.find(person_id).name
and it worked.
I just wanted to display the name on my grid. But thanx for replying.